# Can tailwind colors be referenced from CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have some custom colors in my tailwind.config.js:

```js
colors: {
  primary: {
    500: '#0E70ED',
    600: '#0552b3'
  }
}
```

I want to use them in my CSS files. Is there a way to replace `#0e70ed` below with `primary-500`?

```css
.prose a.custom-link {
  color: #0e70ed;
}
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `theme()` function.

Your colors

```js
colors: {
  primary: {
    500: '#0E70ED',
    600: '#0552b3'
  }
}
```

will be available in CSS files as

```css
.prose a.custom-link {
  color: theme('colors.primary.500');
}
```

More info [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme)

Comment: `color: theme("colors.gray.400");` worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't make it work in jsx e.g. `style={{ '--bg-color': 'theme("colors.dark.100")' }}`

Comment: @Qwerty it needs to be processed with PostCSS and PostCSS itself doesn't handle HTML. Instead either define variable in Tailwind class like `[--bg-color:theme('colors.dark.100')] bg-[--bg-color]` so TW could read it (see [example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/T8qciMj3Xn)) or use another way of defining bg color. Depends on your task (which I don't know what is therefore answer may differ)

Answer (score 16):

Why not directly use tailwind here ?

```css
.prose a.custom-link {
  @apply text-primary-500;
}
```

If you want to access it in JS, you can use [`resolveConfig`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script)

```js
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig'
import tailwindConfig from '@/tailwind.config.js'
const twFullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig)

...
mounted() {
  console.log('tw', twFullConfig.theme.colors['primary-500'])
}
```

Comment: Thank you, kissu. Works like a charm. Hadn't looked at this part of the tailwind docs. Is there any relationship between tailwind's `@apply` and the abandoned CSS `@apply` feature?

Comment: Nope, there is nothing in common between the 2 and it's a good thing that the CSS draft got abandoned, this way there is no "conflict" between the 2. Answer from Adam here: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/627

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Apply works yes. In my case I needed to style svg element while using tailwind 2.x and I had to use `theme` to get the color.

Comment: The simplest solution! You don't have to set anything in your tailwind config, and you don't need to use the theme function either! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

With theme its also possible to get single source of truth using css variables and inside tailwind variables as follows. Thanks to Ihar Aliakseyenka for the answer.

(It seems like tailwind provides both the theme() and colors variable by default)

```
/* globals.css */
:root {
  --primary: theme(colors.slate.900);
  --secondary: theme(colors.slate.100);
}
```

And

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "var(--primary)"
        secondary: "var(--secondary)"
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Then you can use

```
body {
  background-color: var(--primary);
  color: var(--secondary);
}
```

Or..

```
<div className='bg-primary text-secondary'> </>
```

And its all consistent

Comment: `colors.slate.100` wouldn't work for me without being wrapped in quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276977/can-tailwind-colors-be-referenced-from-css#comment136917868_67281604 worked.

Comment: Adding here, tailwind docs recommends against using abstract names for colors. And speaking from experience, companies rarely change their brand colors. If they go from, say, green to blue, it's a one time sed operation.

Answer (score -3):

It's better to avoid creating new classes and use the ones Tailwind offers so you keep the CSS generated as small as possible.
In [TailwindCSS docs you can find a more detailed explanation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#avoiding-premature-abstraction)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not helping and is not true either, you can totally have your own classes while not expanding the size of the final bundle if you're skipping the default ones.