# Nuxt and Windi, Can I get current theme in windi.config.ts?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, themes, windicss

I created a `theme.ts` where I'm deteting the site "brand" by the hostname (based in the [awesome starter nuxt3 repository](https://github.com/viandwi24/nuxt3-awesome-starter/blob/main/utils/theme.ts) versoin) like so:

**utils/theme.ts**

```
export type IThemeSettingOptions = 'light' | 'system' | 'foo' | 'bar'

export type ITheme = 'light' | 'foo' | 'bar'

export const availableThemes: {
  key: IThemeSettingOptions
  text: string
}[] = [
    { key: 'light', text: 'Light' },
    { key: 'system', text: 'System' },
    { key: 'foo', text: 'Foo' },
    { key: 'bar', text: 'Bar' },
  ]

export function ThemeManager() {
  // composable
  const themeUserSetting = useCookie<IThemeSettingOptions>('theme')

  // methods
  const getUserSetting = (): IThemeSettingOptions => {
    return themeUserSetting.value || 'system'
  }

  const getSiteTheme = (): ITheme => {
    try {
      const host = location.hostname
      const sites = {
        'foo.whitelabel.com': 'foo',
        'bar.whitelabel.com': 'bar'
      }

      if (sites[host]) {
        return sites[host]
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return 'light' // This means generic styles, no customizable brand
    }
  }

  // state
  const themeSetting = useState<IThemeSettingOptions>('theme.setting', () =>
    getSiteTheme()
  )

  const themeCurrent = useState<ITheme>('theme.current', () =>
    process.client ? getSiteTheme() : 'light'
  )

  // init theme
  const init = () => {
    themeSetting.value = getSiteTheme()
  }

  // lifecycle
  onBeforeMount(() => init())

  onMounted(() => {
    themeCurrent.value = getSiteTheme()
  })

  return {
    themeSetting,
    themeCurrent,
    getUserSetting,
    getSiteTheme
  }
}
```

I know of this [color mode](https://color-mode.nuxtjs.org/) that nuxt offers. But As I'm using [windicss](https://windicss.org/) I would like to have a different config file/object for every theme/brand.

I tried like this in the `windi.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'windicss/helpers';
import type { Plugin } from 'windicss/types/interfaces';
import { ThemeManager } from './utils/theme';

console.log(ThemeManager().themeCurrent)
// etc..
```

But this won't log anything in the console

is this posible? if not, a similar workaround? (perhaps with tailwindcss)

I want to do this so the `primary` color is different for `foo` than for `bar` brand, lets say something like this:

**windi.config.ts**

```
const MyThemes = {
  light: {
    colors: {
      green: {
        DEFAULT: '#3BA670'
      },
      blue: {
        DEFAULT: '#0096F0'
      }
    }
  },
  foo: {
    colors: {
      green: {
        DEFAULT: '#3BA675'
      },
      blue: {
        DEFAULT: '#0096F5'
      }
    }
  },
  bar: {
    colors: {
      green: {
        DEFAULT: '#3BA67F'
      },
      blue: {
        DEFAULT: '#0096FF'
      }
    }
  }
}

const MyTheme = MyThemes['foo'] // or 'bar' or 'light'


export default defineConfig({
  // etc..
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: MyTheme.colors.green,
        // etc.. 
      }
    },
  }
  // etc..
})
```

Comment: So, you're looking [for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67278884/8816585)? Not sure to fully understand sorry.

Comment: Basically what i want is to get which theme is selected ( `foo`, `bar` or `light`) from the windi config file

Comment: I'm not sure it's Windi's job to keep track of a theme. You are the one in charge of tracking that one. It's like a light/dark mode switch: you have a state tracking it and using the according CSS. If you have a key/value pair kind of system, you pass in the chosen one and the CSS will be chosen accordingly. IMO, it's not the opposite: CSS will not dictate it.

Comment: Here is my answer to what you're trying to achieve here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382023/8816585

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm explaining myself properly so I edited the question with the last bit, does that make sense @kissu? thanks!

Comment: your last link seems to be to define a specific class depending a prop. I would like to define the whole `colors` from windi (or tailwind if it's easier) depending the selected theme

Comment: The idea is exactly the same, you have a mapping in your CSS framework (either Windi or Tailwind), you pass it a mapping. So basically, you need to have an object telling which theme is linked to which color. Then, you pass the name of the theme to the color and it spits you the exact classes. Since you cannot have [dynamic classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) for performance reasons, you still need to struggle with creating that mapping yourself. Otherwise, it will bloat the page of your user quite a lot.

Comment: Another approach would be to rewrite all the root variables by some other values but I guess that a theme comes with something more than just colors, so it's not really an option...

Comment: Perhaps is because I'm very new to nuxt3 (been working for years with nuxt2 but they way of using it is very different) or Windi, and I'm not fully understanding what you are suggesting.. do you want to submit an answer with an example of your first suggestion?

Comment: I've submitted an answer. I don't think it's a Nuxt2 > Nuxt3 issue so far. More of a way of how utility CSS frameworks work. It can be quite complex when you want to have some highly dynamic things done, for sure. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to get the actual value in JS of a specific token in Tailwind, you can use the following as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67278884/8816585).

```js
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig'
import tailwindConfig from '@/tailwind.config.js'
const twFullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig)

...
mounted() {
  console.log('tw', twFullConfig.theme.colors['primary-500'])
}
```

2. And if you want to have something dynamic depending of a specific variable, you need to map it to an object and you'll get your classes as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382023/8816585). This is quite handy if you want something dynamic while using an utility-based CSS framework with a proper design system.
3. Tailwind [does not allow dynamic classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) for performance reasons, hence why such mapping is a necessary evil.

[UnoCSS](https://github.com/unocss/unocss) is probably the most flexible solution that I know but it's still not adapted to solve an issue like that. Neither is the usage of using some CSS variables and overwriting them on the fly since a design system is based on far more things than just a color or a size.

TLDR: theming is hard and requires quite some hand-made mapping to be done efficiently. I've tried that at a client and it's complex quite early, especially if you think about a way of doing that dynamically.

I've tried [that one](https://github.com/antfu/windicss-runtime-dom) and [twind's shim](https://twind.dev/handbook/the-shim.html#frontmatter-title). It's feasible to have it on runtime (if needed) but quite tricky for sure.

Comment: Thank you sou much for taking the time for writing an answer but I don't think we are understanding each other. I don't need to get the value of a color from tailwind/windi, I want to set dinamically the colors object. I don't know if you saw that I edited my question and added this line `const MyTheme = MyThemes['foo'] // or 'bar' or 'light'` the problem is that I don't know which value is set in the `ThemeManager()` from the `utils/theme.ts` file

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet you can't set the colors dynamically. The tokens are meant to be static, like saying what could be used. Then you pick one of them from what's available. My answer is giving both aspects or reaching the available tokens + how to use them depending of a given variable (in point `2.`). This is basically what you're doing when calling `MyThemes['foo']`, `'foo'` being a runtime dynamic variable coming from somewhere else I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on [CSS vars (Custom Properties)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) IMHO you could simplify this.

1. Set a class on the html based on theme, for instance `<html class="dark">...</html>` or `<html class="foo">...</html>`. You can accomplish this in the [nuxt.config.ts app section](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#head) or the color module you mentioned.

```
  app: {
    // https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#head
    head: {
      htmlAttrs: {
        lang: 'en',
        class: 'foo', // Here you could an environment variable
      },
    },
  },
```

3. Set colors on a stylesheet.

```css
// theme.css

:root {
  --color-primary: #3BA670; /* or Whatever value you like, HSL, RGBA, colornames, ecc */
  --color-error: darkred;
}

html.foo {
  --color-primary: #3BA675;
  --color-error: mediumvioletred;
}

html.bar {
  --color-primary: orange;
  --color-error: indianred;
}
```

Finally in your windi.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  // etc..
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: 'var(--color-primary)',
        error: 'var(--color-error)',
        // etc.. 
      }
    },
  }
  // etc..
})
```

Also, if you have a solid color system you can omit extending colors and just overide the windi palette and implement yours.